# Connecting from Mac OS host to local Fedora guest OS in VirtualBox

Tags: mac, virtualbox, apache-http-server, fedora

I’m having troubles connecting to Apache web server that is running inside my VirtualBox Fedora guest OS.

This is my set up:

- **Host:** Mac OS X
- **Guest:** Fedora 22
- **Network adapter:** NAT
- **Apache web server:** running on Fedora guest under `localhost:8090`

On the Mac OS host, I do a `netstat`:

```
sebastian$ netstat
Active Internet connections
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)    
tcp4       0      0  172.26.6.51.49515      10.0.2.15.8090         SYN_SENT   
tcp4       0      0  172.26.6.51.49514      10.0.2.15.8090         SYN_SENT   
tcp4       0      0  172.26.6.51.49513      a23-46-123-27.de.http  ESTABLISHED
```

I can reach the Fedora host through SSH, using `172.26.6.51`. I want to reach the webserver that is running on my Fedora guest. I’m trying to do that by entering this into my browser on my Mac host: `172.26.6.51:49515`.

What am I doing wrong?

Using a bridged network adapter is no option, due to my network setup.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, `netstat` is too deep a networking tool for what you are attempting to do. My guess is that you could just connect to the Fedora guest OS directly like this:

```
172.26.6.51:8090
```

If you want to test this connectivity from the command line, just open up the Terminal window and type in the following:

```
curl -I 172.26.6.51:8090
```

That will make an HTTP request but only show you headers. This is a nicer and more efficient way to test an actual HTTP connection since this is a raw, immediate, non-browser-based connection that won’t be cached the same way a browser would cache it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with VirtualBox' port forwarding functionality.

- **Host IP:** 127.0.0.1
- **Host Port:** 9001
- **Guest IP:** 10.0.2.15
- **Guest Port:** 8090

It doesn't matter which value you use for host port, as long as it's used by another service.